# Jruby "RuntimeHelpers" class is deprecated

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

I am having a project based on JRuby on rails, now I am migrating this project to jruby-9.0.5.0 version.

In the code, ruby is called from Java file as shown below:

```
    String source = new StringBuilder("require 'java'\n" +
        "\n" +
        "java_package 'jrubysource'\n" +

        "class SystemFilePath\n" +
        "  attr_accessor :topDirCmd, :topDirNames\n" +
        "  java_signature 'SystemFilePath(String topDirCmd)'\n" +
        "  def initialize(topDirCmd)\n" +
        "    @topDirCmd = topDirCmd\n" +
        "    setTopDirectoryNames()\n" +
        "  end\n" +
        "\n" +
        "  java_signature 'void setTopDirectoryNames()'\n" +
        "  def setTopDirectoryNames\n" +
        "    Open3.popen3(@topDirCmd) { |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thread|\n" +
        "      out = stdout.read\n" +
        "      err = stderr.read\n" +
        "      if err.size > 0 || out.size == 0\n" +
        "        @topDirNames = nil\n" +
        "        return\n" +
        "      end\n" +
        "      out = out.split(/\\n/).select{|a| a.match(/system_1/) && !a.match(/system_1\\/sim/)}.join(\"\\n\") + \"\\n\";\n" +
        "      topDirNames = out.split(/\\//).select{|a| a.match(/\\n$/) }.map(&:chomp)\n" +
        "      if topDirNames.size == 0 then\n" +
        "        @topDirNames = nil\n" +
        "        return\n" +
        "      end\n" +
        "      @topDirNames = topDirNames.sort.reverse\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "  rescue Exception => e\n" +
        "    @topDirNames = nil\n" +
        "  end\n" +
        "\n" +
        "end\n" +
        "").toString();
    __ruby__.executeScript(source, "system_file_path.rb");
    RubyClass metaclass = __ruby__.getClass("SystemFilePath");
    metaclass.setRubyStaticAllocator(SystemFilePath.class);
    if (metaclass == null) throw new NoClassDefFoundError("Could not load Ruby class: SystemFilePath");
    __metaclass__ = metaclass;
        }


public void setTopDirectoryNames() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    IRubyObject ruby_result = RuntimeHelpers.invoke(__ruby__.getCurrentContext(), this, "setTopDirectoryNames"); //Here i am calling ruby code from java file.
        return;
}
```

Now, according to a [JRuby API document](http://jruby.org/apidocs/org/jruby/javasupport/util/RuntimeHelpers.html) "RuntimeHelpers" class is deprecated.

The document provides no alternative API. Please guide me towards an alternative as this is a blocker for me.

Comment: deprecated doesn't mean you can't use it, just that you shouldn't. If there are currently no alternatives I would probably ignore the warning for now and fix it later. I do realize that that's probably horrible advice depending on the state of the project.

Answer (score 1):

its an internal JRuby API ... you have a similar API available for every IRubyObject :

instead of

```
RuntimeHelpers.invoke(__ruby__.getCurrentContext(), this, "setTopDirectoryNames")
```

try :

```
this.callMethod(__ruby__.getCurrentContext(), "setTopDirectoryNames")
```

Comment: Thanks!!!!!
this.callMethod(__ruby__.getCurrentContext(), "setTopDirectoryNames") worked :)